# Qt 5.2: Exception 0xc000039

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I've got problems with Qt. A few hours ago, all out of the sudden, Qt 5.0.2 did not update my ui_mainwindow.h header file anymore when I changed something in the designer. I noticed, that when I created a new project for testing purposes, that all of the stuff I created in my normal project UI was now in the ui header file of the new test project - my whole UI compiler was broken. I tried different stuff until I decided to update Qt to 5.2 - and it did not show me any errors anymore, it worked! But still, I can't compile. When I press on Debug now, it gives me the exception 0xc000039 - no matter which project to compile.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried to clean the project and reopen it again? Do you have enough file access permissions?

Comment: I The problem is not the project, the problem is Qt. This problem appears on every project. Tried to make a new project for testing, but same effect. And yes, I'm a system admin.

Comment: What exact platform is this?

Comment: What platform do you mean? I'm using Qt 5.2.1 and before that 5.0.2. Also, I'm still on Win XP.